# What makes systemd-nspawn still "unsuitable for secure container setups"?

Tags: security, systemd, lxc

This is stated in the man page for [systemd-nspawn](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html)

> Note that even though these security precautions are taken
>   systemd-nspawn is not suitable for secure container setups. Many of
>   the security features may be circumvented and are hence primarily
>   useful to avoid accidental changes to the host system from the
>   container. The intended use of this program is debugging and testing
>   as well as building of packages, distributions and software involved
>   with boot and systems management.

This very question was subsequently asked [on the mailing list in 2011](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.systemd.devel/2045), but the answer seems to be outdated.

systemd-nspawn contains code to execute `CLONE_NEWNET` using the `--private-network` option now.  This seems to cover the private `AF_UNIX` namespace issue, and I guess the `CAP_NET_RAW` and `CAP_NET_BIND` issues mentioned.

What issues remain at this point and what does for example LXC do in addition to what `systemd-nspawn` can currently do?

Comment: AF_UNIX gets half-isolated with `CLONE_NEWNET`: abstract sockets - separate, filesytem-based - united (unless there are no shared filesystems between host and container). This makes convenient to start X applications barring network for particular application (as Xorg opens both abstract and filesystem UNIX socket).

Comment: The statement that nspawn is "unsuitable for secure container setups" was removed in 2016: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3577 From the man page it appears that nspawn is production-ready and has been for a few years.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LXC is a little bit better because it can run containers *as unpriveleged users*. This is possible with systemd-nspawn, but only for scenarios where you only need one user (instead of multiple), which can be difficult or less secure for multi process in container scenarios. If you want to know why docker, lxc, and systemd-nspawn are inherently not a solid security mechanism, read this: https://opensource.com/business/14/7/docker-security-selinux. Basically, containers still have access to the kernel and any kernel exploit gains control of the entire machine. On a monolithic kernel like Linux, kernel exploits are not uncommon.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. systemd-nspawn supports dropping privileges to a different user: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html

Comment: I am pretty sure all that does is run the console / shell as a non-priveleged user, but run everything else as root. Can you look into that?

Comment: Ok, I take my last statement back. However, it does not have proper subuid/subgid handling, only one unpriveleged user per container.

Comment: Only being able to drop to one unprivileged user per container instead of supporting full subuid/subgid handling isn't a security issue. It's a feature limitation.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just pointing out the difference.

Comment: @DavidTimothyStrauss That was a great link. The sense I'm making of the whole situation is that containers isolation is only for benign processes. And if a malignant program is running in the container as root, think of it's privileges being the same as a malignant root program on the host machine. 

With VM's it's multiple layers of security- root or not. 
 
One question- say I run postgres and http server as two different containers owned by two different unprivileged users. Is this any more secure than running the same as two different unprivileged users on the host machine itself?

Comment: I would recommend referencing https://people.kernel.org/brauner/runtimes-and-the-curse-of-the-privileged-container for further evaluation of how uid namespaces limit the severity of vulnerabilities.